# Someone upvoting all of my answers

Tags: support, reputation, badges

Today, I just received an upvote on 9 of my answers at about the same time. I've read a little on here and saw that "serial" upvoting causes you to lose the rep after. My question is, I also got a badge because of this, will I lose the badge as well?

Also, if they upvote 9 of my answers, will the legitimate one that they upvoted first get it's rep removed as well? Or just the other 8?

Comment: You already had the (mortarboard) badge before today. But you'd get to keep it anyway even if it wasn't legit.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm talking about the "Nice Answer" badge

Comment: You'd still get to keep that. And it's not completely not legit - it already had 9 upvotes before it went to 10.

Comment: I'd suggest flagging one of your answers, making note of this thread, so that mods will see that clear and up front if they ever investigate you for vote fraud.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those up-votes were very close to each other, possibly by the same person. That will likely be taken for serial voting and reverted.

About the nice answer badge: you keep it. Next time you were to get that badge, you will not get it to compensate for the one you got this time, in case the current question's upvote count is still below 10. Since badges are never revoked, you just don't get one next time.